# Why is it wrong to throw exception in constructor of class

Tags: c#

I have a class which has Id assignment at constructor level. I want id parameter to be more than 0. If it is 0 or negative it causes problem so I want to throw exception if value passed does not meet the criteria:

```
public class Employee
{
    int _id;
    string name;

    public Employee(int id, string name)
    {
        if(id<1) throw new Exception("ID must be positive, greater than 0);
        _id=id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

It isn't wrong, it's a valid thing to do to protect the invariants of your class. If you didn't do this, it would be possible to create an object in an invalid state, which you wouldn't want.

I would suggest you use a more appropriate exception type, though. Throwing `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` would be closer to what you're actually communicating to the caller.

From [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception(v=vs.110).aspx):

> An ArgumentOutOfRangeException exception is thrown when a method is invoked and at least one of the arguments passed to the method is not null and contains an invalid value that is not a member of the set of values expected for the argument.

Comment: I would also recommend that if you don't accept values of less then 0 then make it a unit. Unless you're worried about mathematical operations your types should reflect your restrictions. Its a hint to whomever is using the class